# Word for a very nimble boat?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a metaphor describing a switch from a very static environment to a very dynamic one.

> Instead of trying to turn the Titanic, it'll be like steering a <boat here>

What kind of boat could go into the metaphor?

The best I came up with was "power boat"

Comment: It's _the Titanic_. Ships' names are proper nouns.

Comment: @KateBunting nice catch, thanks! Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Phil Sweet would love to answer this one, I'm sure.

Comment: Does it need to be a boat or will any aquatic craft do? ... _it'll be like steering a jet ski._

Comment: @KillingTime you're very right, there's certainly no need for it to be strictly a boat. As long as the metaphor conveys the intended meaning. Jet ski is probably the best so far, since it can change direction quickly *and* it's fast, perhaps in metaphorical terms signifying that it can adapt quickly to the new direction.

Comment: @user405662 [Jet Sprint Boat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv0pI_9JqaU)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [Kayak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayak) could work.
They are light & maneuverable and traditionally the Inuit used them to travel and hunt in the arctic ocean.

If you would rather compare to a ship which carried passengers for long voyages then a [Catamaran](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamaran) like Polynesians used to explore the Pacific could work too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question but if we look for a small, nimble and long-established boat, the *coracle* is pre-eminent on all three counts:

> Coracle = a small, round boat that is made by stretching animal skin over a wooden frame
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coracle)

The definition does not cover all aspects of this ancient vessel. Here is an extract from a long and relevant article:

> The coracle is one of the simplest and strangest-looking boats ever designed for use on our rivers. It has been used by hunter gatherers for many centuries and is thought to date back to pre-Roman times. The coracle is also one of the most unusual boats to paddle along Britain’s inland waterways. Down the centuries it has been used for everything from fishing and transport to postal deliveries and poaching.
>
> [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/23Fbd5ybr2CFG9BWYYZ7MZh/coracles-the-surprising-history-of-britain-s-strangest-boat)

Also see

> [Coracle Society](https://www.coraclesociety.org.uk/coracles)

And here is one in use:

[image]

> [Canal and River Trust](https://canalrivertrust.org.uk/news-and-views/news/rare-opportunity-to-sail-back-in-time-in-traditional-coracle-at-pocklington-canal-discovery-day)

Answer (score 0):

Coracles are certainly nimble. But, as you're talking about "a switch from a very static environment to a very dynamic one," perhaps

*Like steering a [RIB](https://www.google.com/search?q=RIB+(boat)&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjMn7DV17nwAhUT5hoKHT8qB9gQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=RIB+(boat)&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoECAAQQ1DAUliBcmCqdmgAcAB4AIABR4gBygOSAQE3mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=Mk6WYMy-BpPMa7_UnMAN&bih=677&biw=1354&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en).*

RIBs may be better-known in the UK than the US though. But then, so are coracles!

*Like steering a rigid inflatable* maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP has clarified that any aquatic craft will be acceptable, my suggestion is

> Instead of trying to turn the Titanic, it'll be like steering a **Jet Ski**.

A [Jet Ski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Ski) is a nimble craft known for being able to change direction very rapidly.

While the term Jet Ski is a brand name owned by Kawasaki, it's used as a generic term for these kinds of personal water craft.

Comment: Jet ski is also probably a more widely known term than some of the more obscure boats mentioned here. No point in using a metaphor/simile if it refers to something nobody understands.